# Saving an int variable "highscore" with sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I am developing a game and I have written all the code, including the code that makes sure the highscore int is updated. Now I am wondering how I could save this int with SharedPreferences. I am an beginning programmer, so could you give me all the steps I would have to do?

The variable highscore is in the MainView and I came to the understanding that you would have to save something with shared preferences in the MainActivity.

Comment: Show us what you have done and where the error is...

Comment: Ps I have only one highscore which is drawn in the middle top of the screen

Comment: There is no error, I woul just like to know how I would do that, I don't understand what I have to do when I search it on the internet...

Comment: I seriously doubt you have made any search... this is what I got googling for "android sharedpreferences tutorial": http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm **it took me 2 seconds**

Comment: @SachinG I don't understand how I would do that with an integer variable

Comment: @user3654043: just replace `putLong` and `getLong` with `putInt` and `getInt`?

Comment: @DerGolem That sort of tutorials show me how I would save Textview, buttons, or something like that

Comment: You can't save a Button. You mean a Button's text. Read that tutorial  **in full**, and read it **twice**. It's all there.

Comment: I have one more question @DerGolem, _public static final **String** Name = "nameKey";_ would you need to replace the String with Int or something like that?

Comment: NO. The key has a **name**, which is **always a String**. But it also has a **value**, which is, in your case, the highScore **int** to save (and to retrieve).

Comment: But how would I then get the value to be the highscore int,which is in my view class, in my activity class @DerGolem

Comment: @user184994 has a good answer (and you should accept it)... I think it says it all.

Answer (score 2):

I like to create a simple helper class to deal with the saving and loading of values. That way you can keep all of the keys on one place.

```
public class PreferencesHelper {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    private static final String FILE_NAME = "file_name";

    public static final String KEY_HIGH_SCORE = "high_score";

    public PreferencesHelper(Context context) {
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    /**
     * Save the specified value to the shared preferences
     * 
     * @param key
     *            The key of the value you wish to load
     * @param defValue
     *            The value to store
     */
    public void save(String key, int value) {
        prefs.edit().putInt(key, value).commit();
    }


    /**
     * Load the specified value from the shared preferences
     * 
     * @param key
     *            The key of the value you wish to load
     * @param defValue
     *            The default value that will be returned if nothing is found
     */
    public int loadInt(String key, int defValue) {
        return prefs.getInt(key, defValue);
    }

}
```

Then, in your activity you just write:

```
PreferencesHelper prefs = new PreferencesHelper(this);

// Save
prefs.save(PreferencesHelper.KEY_HIGH_SCORE, 25000);

//Load
prefs.loadInt(PreferencesHelper.KEY_HIGH_SCORE, 0);
```

Comment: when I write that last bit of code in my activity I get an error: _Syntax error on tokens, ConstructorHeaderName expected instead_

Comment: and I still don't understand how this piece of code would recognize that it has to save the highscore variable _public int highscore_